# Understanding send/suspend/dispatch in Racket Web Framework

Tags: webserver, scheme, racket

I am trying to understand the example that relates to the send/suspend/dispatch code in the Racket Web Framework Tutorial http://docs.racket-lang.org/continue/.

For ease here is the code that puzzles me:

```
#lang web-server/insta
; start: request -> response
   (define (start request)
      (show-counter 0 request))

; show-counter: number request -> doesn't return
; Displays a number that's hyperlinked: when the link is pressed,
; returns a new page with the incremented number.
(define (show-counter n request)
  (local [(define (response-generator embed/url)
            (response/xexpr
             `(html (head (title "Counting example"))
                    (body
                     (a ((href ,(embed/url next-number-handler)))
                        ,(number->string n))))))

          (define (next-number-handler request)
            (show-counter (+ n 1) request))]

    (send/suspend/dispatch response-generator)))
```

I have two questions:

(Most important) Where is embed/url defined? I can't see that it is defined in this code, but my understanding of continuations is rudimentary so it may be I am missing something.

What is the purpose of local? I can remove it and the code seems to work just the same.

Comment: In some #langs used in Racket internal defines are not allowed. So `local` is used. it's similar to a `let`.

Comment: As Rptx writes, in this case local can be omitted. It makes clear though, that response-generator is a local function (and thus it can close over values n and request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function embed/url is the argument to response-generator:

```
(define (response-generator embed/url) ...)
```

When `(send/suspend/dispatch response-generator)` is evaluated, the following happens:

```
1. a procedure `p` given a "continuation" (here next-number-handler)" 
   generates an url
2. the function `response-generator` is called with `p` as argument.
3. the page `(html ... ,(embed-url next-number-handler)) is generated
   (note: (embed-url next-number-handler) calls `p` and the resulting url is inserted into the page)

4. [send]     the page is sent to the client
5. [suspend]  the server suspends the program
6. [dispatch] receives an request generated by clicking link whose url were
              generated in 3.  The handler associated to the url 
              (here next-number-handler) is looked up, and the handler 
              is called.
```

Although not necessary for using `send/suspend/dispatch` here is a sketch:

```
(define (send/suspend/dispatch response-generator )
  (let/ec escape
    (define (callback->url callback)
      (let/ec return-url
        (escape (callback (send/suspend return-url)))))
    (send/back (response-generator callback->url))))
```

Comment: So I think I am closer now. If embed/url is the argument for response-generator then it is provided to response-generator from within send/suspend/dispatch when send/suspend/dispatch is running. It maybe that I don't understand how send/suspend/dispatch operates. Does send/suspend/dispatch capture the continuation - if so how does it do it (roughly)?

Comment: It more or less uses call/cc. In practise it captures a delimited continuation.  How it captures it the continuation is not relevant for using the send/suspend/dispatch though. It is interesting though, so if you are curious see the papers http://www.ccs.neu.edu/racket/pubs/hosc07-sk-mf.pdf and http://repository.readscheme.org/ftp/papers/sw2003/WebUI.pdf

Comment: I take your point that I don't need to understand this to make use of it. At least now I have a better mental image of what is going on. Thanks,